# Number of Threads per each request in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am trying to understand the architecture of Struts 2 as it is provided in [this link](https://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-architecture-and-flow).

I think the Servlet container creates a new thread for each request and it is the controller(a servlet which is the entry point to struts 2) that should fill in the HttpServletResponse. But in this diagram it is shown that the `HttpServletResponse` is sent to the client (browser) by the `ActionInvocation` (not the controller). The entry point to Struts 2 is the Controller (see the figure in the link mentioned). I think for each request from the client the Servlet Container creates a new thread and calls the service method of the Controller.

Does the Sturts2 framework also creates one more thread `ActionInvocation` that sends the response to the client or it is the Controller that sends the `HttpServletResponse` to the client?

I am new to Struts 2 and trying to understand the flow. Please help me in understanding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the Sturts2 framework also creates one more thread ActionInvocation that sends the response to the client

No, it uses the same thread as request.

If you need to learn more about objects and how they were scoped in struts2 container see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202285/573032) answer.