# Struts 2.x migration - How to achieve same URL pattern as Struts 1.x

Tags: struts2, migration, struts-1

Currently I am working in Struts migration task from 1.x to 2.x. The major problem I am facing is that change in URL pattern.

In Struts 1, we use url pattern as below.

**Note: multiple methods resides in each action class**

`https://<host-name>/xxx.do?method=begin`

After struts 2, we are following below url pattern

`https://<host-name>/xxx_begin.action`

`struts.xml`:(used wildcard mapping)

`<action name="xxx_*" method ="{1}" class = "foo.Myaction"><result name="success"> myjsp.jsp</result></action>`

**Question:**

Is there any way to achieve the same url pattern as mentioned for Struts 1 in Struts 2?

Since its very big project, it is very complicated to update each and every place where the invocation happens.
I have searched through many sources and found, it is easy to configure **.action** extension to **.do** extension by simply adding the below config in `struts.xml`

`<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"/>`

But how to achieve the method invocation as same as Struts 1.

If there is solution, also please mention how to add the action mapping in `struts.xml`?

Comment: May be with the custom action mapper.

Comment: Roman C -  Is there any sources I can refer to, so that I can understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

Struts actions are mapped using the [ActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html). You can use different action mapper class configured to the application. The action mapper used by default is not able to map URLs to actions the same way you did in Struts 1. Some action mappers are available via plugins but it's not possible to map parameters to the action. *Only* action name and namespace are mapped.

It is important that before you write your own action mapper to understand [What is the role of the action mapper in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068240/573032) and its [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202285/573032).

There's also special parameter used by DMI, which is using a method prefix parameter name. If you find a way how to change the parameter to use its value as a name and add a `method:` prefix. The documentation said that a [method prefix](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html#method-prefix) can be somehow overridden.

> With method-prefix, instead of calling `baz` action’s `execute()` method (by default if it isn’t overridden in `struts.xml` to be something else), the `baz` action’s `anotherMethod()` will be called.

Struts 2 can be extended via providing a [custom action mapper](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html#custom-actionmapper).